# Is there no constructor call when pointer is created?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, delete-operator

When I ran this program destructor of class A is called twice but constructor is called once.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(){cout<<"constructor\n";}
    ~A(){cout<<"destructor\n";}
};

int main()
{

    A a1;
    A *ap=&a1;
    delete ap;

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor
destructor
destructor
```

Comment: You are deleting something that never was allocated with `new`. That's wrong.

Comment: Why do you expect a constructor call when you initialize a pointer without using `new`?

Comment: A pointer is a representation of the address (place in memory) of a variable, creating one won't create another variable. Its like a road sign to your house, putting up a road sign doesn't require building another house.

Comment: Constructor is called when an object is created. `A * ap = new A` will call constructor, but `A *ap = &a1;` won't because it just takes an address of existing object.

Comment: Imagine what the world would be like if you were cloned every time you told someone where you live.

Comment: `ap` is a pointer, you don't create any instance of class with pointer.

Comment: @raymai97 That's not entirely true, you can do so using the `new` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a1` is a plain old variable, so when you declare it, the constructor is called. `ap` is a pointer variable, so declaring it or assigning to it does not call any constructor. `ap` is just a pointer to `a1`.

When you explicitly delete `ap` the destructor is called, and when `a1` falls out of scope the destructor is called again. As noted in the comments, calling `delete` on a pointer that wasn't initialized with `new` is wrong, and will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @nuiun The fact that `a1` is an automatic variable is irrelevant. The same would apply to instance and static members and static variables.